# Intellij: what mouse/selector mode am I in, and how do I get out of it?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

This morning, while using intelllij, I am experiencing problematic behaviour. For one thing, I am unable to accurately use my mouse pointer. If I attempt to highlight a variable name by double-clicking on it; the pointer doesn't change to a caret, but remains as an arrow, and the whole class, inside the `{}`, is highlighted. This is driving me crazy, and I know that this is exclusively intellij, this morning, because all other apps, allow for standard mouse/selection behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The standard "turn it off and back on again" worked, unsurprisingly. So, whatever it was, I'm glad to have seen the back of it.